# Two measurable sets have the same measure if their intersection with a non-measurable set have the same exterior measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},m)$, a non-measurable set $E$ such that $m^*(E)=m(X)$ and two measurable sets $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, I would like to prove that $m(A)=m(B)$ if $m^*(A\cap E)=m^*(B\cap E)$ ($m^*$ is the exterior measure induced by $m$).

I have been using Carathéodory’s property of $A$ and $B$ (i.e $m^*(E)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A^c \cap E)$ and the same with $B$), but I have not been able to prove the desired equality. Since the roles of the measurable sets are symmetric, I only need to prove one inequality to imply the other. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For any subset $F\subset X$
$$ \mu^{*}(F) = \inf_{A \textrm{meas, } F \subset A}   \mu(A) $$

For convenience, define also the interior measure
$$\mu_{*}(F) = \sup_{A \textrm{meas, } F \supset A}   \mu(A) $$

It is easy to see that if  $A$ measurable , then
$$\mu(A) = \mu^{*}(A\cap F) + \mu_{*}(A\backslash F)$$

Now, back to the problem at hand. Since $\mu^{*}(E) = \mu(X)$ we have
$$\mu_{*}(X\backslash E)= 0$$ Therefore, for any measurable $A$ we have
$$\mu(A) = \mu^{*}(A\cap E) + \mu_{*}(A\backslash E)=\mu^{*}(A \cap E)$$